# Performing a for-loop on a retrieved array

Tags: java, list, for-loop

Continuing on my attempt at an app and I'm stuck again on the very next object.

Last time I asked about my Performer.java object which receives an array of 5 integers.

This time I am trying to manipulate the data through my Calculations object.

(Please correct me if I am labelling the wrong things objects)

```
import java.util.List;

public class Calculations {

    public static int performCalcs() {
        Performer getInput = new Performer();

        List<Integer> arrayOne = getInput.getUnit();

        for(int i=0 ; i<=arrayOne.size() ; i++) {
            int sumTotal = 0;

            return sumTotal;
        }
    }
}
```

I am literally stuck. I know it doesn't make any sense, but what I am trying to do is add up all the numbers in my array and also calculate the average of the numbers in my array.

I think I did the "i" correctly, and I was able to retrieve my array into arrayOne, but don't know how to implement the "i" and make it perform either addition or multiplication until i<=arrayOne.size.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Don't rush it. Go through some tutorials, and read some code.

Comment: Bingo, go read a book.  It will make life so much easier and programming a lot more fun.

Comment: Another thing: `i<=arrayOne.size()` you might want to replace `<=` with `<`

Comment: An important note: You don't use an array, you use a list. In Java -and I think also in C++ and in .Net- it is a complete different object with different methods and behavior.

Comment: Not sure this deserves the -1s, the question is basic yes, but well formatted and clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i=0 ; i<=arrayOne.size() ; i++){
    int sumTotal = 0;

    return sumTotal;

}
```

What you are doing in the above code, is that you are entering the loop, and after the first interation you return sumTotal (which will be 0)

This is what you want to do

```
 int sumTotal = 0; // declare the variable you want to to summerize outside the loop. If you declare it inside the loop it will be garbage collected once the loop finishes and the variable is lost
    for(int i=0 ; i<arrayOne.size() ; i++){
        sumTotal+=arrayOne.get(i); // add the value that is at the current index each iteration

    }
//After the loop, somTotal will have the total added value of the integers in the `List`. Now you can continue from here
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanations. I gotta go back and find reviews for for loops instead of asking such broad questions. Sorry everyone, and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

- You should move `sumTotal` outside the **for loop**. Otherwise the `sumTotal` variable is re-initialized every time.
- You should loop till `i < arrayOne.size()`. O.w. you'll get an IndexOutOfBoundsException
- You do retrieve the i-th number in this way: `arrayOne.get(i)`
- Then compute the `average` value by dividing `sumTotal` for the number of values in the `arrayOne` list.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Calculations {

    public static int performCalcs() {

        Performer getInput = new Performer();

        List<Integer> arrayOne = getInput.getUnit();

        int sumTotal = 0;

        // Sum the numbers in the array 
        // Repeat until i < arrayOne.size()
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOne.size(); i++) {
            int num = arrayOne.get(i);
            sumTotal += num;
        }
        // Check that the array is not empty.
        // If it is not, compute the average, o.w. return 0.
        double avg = arrayOne.isEmpty() ? .0 : (sumTotal / arrayOne.size());
        System.out.println("average: " + avg);
        return avg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Return. :) So much for the race!

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Thanks Maroun Maroun. I see now. :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use for-each loop:

```
int sumTotal = 0;

for(Integer val: arrayOne) {
    sumTotal += val.intValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note how sumTotal is returned within the loop, meaning that on the very first time through the loop it returns the first value. You want it to say

```
import java.util.List;


public class Calculations {

public static int performCalcs(){


    Performer getInput = new Performer();

    List<Integer> arrayOne = getInput.getUnit();

    int sumTotal = 0;
    for(int i=0 ; i<arrayOne.size() ; i++){
        sumTotal+=arrayOne.get(i);
    }
    return sumTotal;
}

}
```

returns work in java (and most programming languages) that there can be many in a function, and the first one that it finds the function ends and returns whatevers after the return, for example

```
public double someFunction(int a){
    if (a!=5){
        return a;
    }else{
        return 12;
    }
    return 999; //this return is never used under any circumstances because the function has already returned, good IDEs won't even allow it
}
```

Two returns and it uses the first one it finds

Edit:
As Maroun Maroun correctly states the for loop should be

```
for(int i=0 ; i<arrayOne.size() ; i++){
```

not

```
for(int i=0 ; i<=arrayOne.size() ; i++){
```

This is because java array indexes start at 0, so an array with 5 entries will have indexes 0,1,2,3,4

Answer (score 0):

To sum all the numbers in any `Iterable` you need to do this:

```
//Declare the variable to hold the total outside the loop.
int total = 0;

//Loop over the integers to sum.
for (Integer i : integers)
{
  //Add the current integer to the total.
  total += i;
}

//The total will now equal the sum of all the integers.
System.out.println("Total: " + total);
System.out.println("Average: " + (total / integers.size()));
```

The two important bits that your code was missing are:

- the total variable must be declared outside the loop else it is simple reinitialized with each iteration.
- you need to add the integers values together.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should look like this

```
public class Calculations {
```

public static int performCalcs(){

```
Performer getInput = new Performer();

List<Integer> arrayOne = getInput.getUnit();

for(int i=0 ; i<=arrayOne.size() ; i++){
    int sumTotal += i;
}
    return sumTotal;
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

you should pull the sum init and the return out of your loop

```
public static int performCalcs(){


    Performer getInput = new Performer();
    List<Integer> arrayOne = getInput.getUnit();
    int sumTotal = 0;

    for(int i=0 ; i < arrayOne.size(); i++){
        return sumTotal += arrayOne.get(i);
    }

    return sumTotal;
}
```

Comment: `i<=arrayOne.size()` - replace `<=` with `<`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are using "return" inside your loop.  The i++ part is fine.  Use the return outside of the loop.  All of the answers above show this.

If you use "return" in your loop, it will only iterate once.

Answer (score 0):

Move `int sumTotal = 0;` out of the loop (above) and `return ...` also (below). Inside the loop put `sumTotal += arrayOne[I]`. You are learning the hard way, aren't you?